# How to collect all specified href's?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

In this test model I can collect the `href` value for the **first** `('tr', class_='rowLive')`, I've tried to create a loop to collect all the others `href` but it always gives `IndentationError: expected an indented block` or says I'm trying to use `find` instead of `find_all`.

How should I proceed to collect all `href`?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/pt/betlive/9'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"}

site = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(site.content, 'html.parser')
jogos = soup.find_all('tr', class_='rowLive')

jogo = jogos[0]
linksgame = jogo.find('a', href=True).attrs['href'].strip()

print(linksgame)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jogos` returns a list, you can loop over it and `find()` an `a` for every iteration:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/pt/betlive/9"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
}

site = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(site.content, "html.parser")
jogos = soup.find_all("tr", class_="rowLive")

for tag in jogos:
    print(tag.find("a", href=True)["href"])
```

Or:

```
print([tag.find("a", href=True)["href"] for tag in jogos])
```

Comment: My friend, thank you very much, I'm just waiting for the Stack to authorize me to approve your answer as the solution and I'll give you due credit!