# Save .csv file with names in first column and links in second column (IndentationError: expected an indented block)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When trying to run the script the following error appears:

```
line 16
    for tag in jogos:
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

My expected result is:

```
COLUMN 1             COLUMN 2
Team A v Team B      LINK HREF
Team C v Team D      LINK HREF
Team E v Team F      LINK HREF
Team G v Team H      LINK HREF
```

**Another problem** is that specifying data delivery with `namelist` and `linkslist` is only delivering the first value and not all possible values.

In this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68446386/11462274), via `print`, like this:

`print(tag.find("a", href=True).get_text().strip())`
Or this:
`print(tag.find("a", href=True)["href"])`

The result delivers the complete list of values, but when I define a specific name like `namelist` and `linkslist`, it stops returning the complete list and delivers only one value.

Full Script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/pt/betlive/9"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
}

site = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(site.content, "html.parser")
jogos = soup.find_all("tr", class_="rowLive")

with open ('Lista_de_Jogos.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='UTF8') as f:

for tag in jogos:
    namelist = tag.find("a", href=True).get_text().strip()
    linkslist = tag.find("a", href=True)["href"]

row = namelist + ';' + linkslist + '\n'
f.write(row)
```

Comment: The error message ‘expected an indented block’ couldn’t be clearer.

Comment: Note: you can pass `strip=True` to `get_text()`: `get_text(strip=True)` instead of using `.get_text().strip()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is obvious. Since your using a context manager - `with(...)` you should write the code *within* that indentation block.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/pt/betlive/9"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
}

site = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(site.content, "html.parser")
jogos = soup.find_all("tr", class_="rowLive")

with open("Lista_de_Jogos.csv", "a", newline="", encoding="UTF8") as f:
    for tag in jogos:
        namelist = tag.find("a", href=True).get_text().strip()
        linkslist = tag.find("a", href=True)["href"]

        row = namelist + ";" + linkslist + "\n"
        f.write(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to indent the code after the 'with open' statement.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/pt/betlive/9"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
}

site = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(site.content, "html.parser")
jogos = soup.find_all("tr", class_="rowLive")
print (jogos)


with open ('Lista_de_Jogos.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='UTF8') as f:

    for tag in jogos:
        
        namelist = tag.find("a", href=True).get_text().strip()
        linkslist = tag.find("a", href=True)["href"]
       
        row = namelist + ';' + linkslist + '\n'
        f.write(row)
```